# explicit template instantiation of explicit operator bool

Tags: c++, template-specialization, explicit-conversion

I'm trying to understand why I get a linker error

```
( error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Foo<int>::operator bool(void)const_ )
```

With the following code.  If I move the definition of Foo::operator bool() to the header, it builds fine.  Apparently there is a problem with the explicit template instantiation, but I'm not seeing it.  Please help me understand why.

Foo.hpp:

```
/* Foo.hpp */
template<class T>
struct Foo {
  T x;
  explicit operator bool() const;
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
/* Foo.cpp */
#include "Foo.hpp"
template <class T>
Foo<T>::operator bool() const {
  return true;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
/* main.cpp */
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Foo<int> foo;
  if (foo)
    std::cout << "works" << std::endl;
}
template Foo<int>::operator bool() const;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explicit template instantiation must have the template definition visible.

So you have to put

```
template Foo<int>::operator bool() const;
```

in Foo.cpp, not main.cpp.

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/qF9evZoW8)

Comment: Apologies, the explicit instantiation __is__ in Foo.cpp, not main.cpp.  Linker error persists.

Comment: Don't change question in a way which invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't, except the edited form is the exact Minimal, Reproducible Example.  I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Demo added BTW, and it works there.

Comment: Thanks Jarod :)  Makes me think this is MSVC specific issue.